# How do I use len to give me number of elements in a list (not the number of letters)?

Tags: python, list, tuples, string-length

I’ve been running into this issue with len and tuples. I want to find out how many elements are in a tuple. So far it works for tuples with at least two elements.

For example:

```py
> data = “cat”, “dog”
> len(data)
2
```

This returns 2. But if I have just one element

```py
> data = “cat”
> len(data)
3
```

This returns 3, because it counts the letters. I want it to return 1, as there is one string in data.

Any ideas of how I can accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: `data = (“cat”,)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is because you're not declaring the tuple correctly, when you want just one item in the tuple you need to use `tup = ('cat',)` with a trailing comma, without the trailing comma python interprets your are talking about a string and therefore returns the length of that string.

#### Example:

**Tuple:**

```py
tup = ('cat',) # notice the trailing comma meaning a tuple
print(len(tup)) # 1
print(type(tup)) # <class 'tuple'>
```

**String:**

```py
tup = ('cat') # notice no trailing comma
print(len(tup)) # 3
print(type(tup)) # <class 'str'>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.